# If the Armenian word for "foot", "otn", really comes from PIE *podm, why did the 'p' disappear?

Tags: proto-indo-european, armenian

If the Armenian word for "foot", "otn", really comes from PIE *podm, why did the 'p' disappear? Why didn't it change into 'h', like in "hing" (five, from *penk<sup>w</sup>e) or "hair" (father, from *ph<sub>2</sub>ter) or "hur" (fire, from *peh<sub>2</sub>wr)?

Comment: To be clear, it's pronounced with an initial *v-*, at least in modern Armenian.  So not totally clear that it disappeared.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What we see in *otn* isn't **p-* > ∅, which isn't a rule in Armenian, but **po-* > *o-*, which probably is. Some comparanda to support this: *ordi* 'child' and *ortʿ* 'calf', both from the o-grade of the root **per-* also seen in Greek πόρτις 'calf', Latin *pariō* 'to birth'; probably *orot* 'thunder' from a different root **per-* also seen in Russian перун 'thunderbolt', Sanskrit पर्जन्य *parjánya* 'raincloud'; possibly *ors* 'hunt, catch' next to Greek πόρκος 'a kind of fishing trap' or, in a different view, Latin *porcus* 'pig' (Martirosyan rejects both of these and instead connects Greek δορκάς/ζορκάς 'roe deer' < **i̭orḱ-*).
*Otn* is from PIE **podm̥*, the accusative of the root noun, but Armenian actually also has a reflex of the thematic noun **pedom* in Classical Armenian *het* 'footstep', with the expected *h-* because here **p-* wasn't followed by **o*.

Comment: Was it pronounced with an initial *v-* in Classical Armenian, like it is in modern Armenian?

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer Presumably not, or it would have been written.

Comment: Not exactly clear to me.  For context, `o` was only introduced in the 11th century, because the '-v' in 'av' was lost, i.e. for words which actually started with a vowel in proto-Armenian.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer *otn* is written ոտն, with ո rather than օ (which is *ō* < *aw*). ո was part of the alphabet from the start.

Comment: `o` (the Armenian one) came from *aw* collapsing to `ō`, but words with `ո` (the Armenian one) generally had an initial consonant in PIE (e.g. ով, որթ, որդի, որբ) or in the origin languages if early loans (e.g. ոսկի, ոլոռ).  (The final `ն` is irrelevant here.)

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer All PIE words had an initial consonant, and it hasn't stopped other daughter languages from developing words starting with vowels. It's less believable to me that 1. multiple consonants (I'm counting \*kʷ, \*p, \*h₃, and [x] in your examples) would independently develop into *w* or *v* word-initially before *o* rather than being lost outright (if that's what you're saying) and 2. people establishing a new writing system just wouldn't write a letter that's there (and for which they have a glyph) than that certain vowels (*o* and *e*) would secondarily develop a glide onset.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest answer, [Beekes 2001](https://www.robertbeekes.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/b109.pdf) p. 171,
is that "*p > h- in anlaut before vowel (> zero before o)" – this is one of the Armenian sound changes. A more nuanced answer is that *p lenited to φ, and disappeared in certain perceptually-challenging contexts such as before *o*  or before a consonant, or *w* after a vowel, or *h* initially before a vowel. The presence of *h* in *hur* "fire" is surprising in light of deletion in *otn*, *ul*, ali-k' *same page): deletion is only before *o*, not *u*.

Comment: Was it pronounced with an initial v- in Classical Armenian, like it is in modern Armenian?